# Unexpected token import-lodash import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, handlebars.js, lodash

While im exploring the plop micro generator , I encountered the above error , 
the code is as follows:

```
import {trimRight, isEmpty} from 'lodash'


const ensurePlural = ( text ) => trimRight( text, "s" ) + "s";

const isNotEmptyFor = ( name ) => {
  return ( value ) => {
    if ( isEmpty( value ) ) return name + " is required";
    return true;
  }
}
```

.....
...
When I run npm run plop I get the following

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {trimRight, isEmpty} from 'lodash'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```